# Fundamentals of inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand how inheritance works in python. I was looking at a simple code and one thing is confusing me. The code is following:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def Name(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        Person.__init__(self,first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def GetEmployee(self):
        return self.Name() + ", " +  self.staffnumber

x = Person("Marge", "Simpson")
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson","1007")
print(x.Name()) 
print(y.GetEmployee())
```

My question is that when are using `Person.__init__()` to call the constructor of baseclass but when we calling Name() method of base class again, instead of using "Person", we are using "self". Can somebody clear this confusion and me understand the how inheritance works in python?

Comment: That is not very Pythonic code, and is probably not the best to learn from! But note that you can use `self.method` to access the superclass implementation **only if the subclass doesn't implement `method`**. The subclass here implements `__init__`, so needs to access the superclass version explicitly (although it should do so with `super`), but doesn't implement `Name`. Try changing it and see what happens!

Comment: One more question, when we need to call a method of parent class we need to pass the child (self) as an argument. Why is that so?

Comment: Because you're not using `super(Employee, self).__init__(first, last)`. Search for information about bound vs. unbound methods; `self.Name` is bound, `Person.__init__` is unbound.

Comment: ok I will read up on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `Employee` class inherits methods from the base `Person` class, including the `__init__` method. So at the top of the class definition, it has `__init__` and `Name` methods.

Then the `Employee` class definition overwrites the `__init__` method that it inherited. In order to call the `__init__` method of `Person`, it has to call `Person.__init__` by name (actually, it could use `super()` as another alternative).

But since `Employee` doesn't overwrite the inherited `Name` method, it can use `self.Name()` to call the `Name` method that it inherited at the top.

Comment: One more question, when we need to call a method of parent class we need to pass the child (self) as an argument. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

The following two methods are equivalent (assuming the "Name" method is never overridden):

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        Person.__init__(self, first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def getEmployee(self):
        return Person.Name(self) + self.staffnumber


class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        Person.__init__(self, first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def getEmployee(self):
        return self.Name() + self.staffnumber
```

In the second example, when self.Name() is called, the instance of the class is "bound" to the function, so the first argument doesn't need to be passed.

Because **init** is being overridden in the Employee subclass, you can't call self.**init**(first, last).  You'll then call Employee.**init**(self, *args) rather than Person.**init**(self, *args).  This will either create an infinite recursion loop, or you'll get an argument error.

As a general rule, when you're overriding a method, you have to use the following notation in the subclass.  ParentClass.methodname(self, *args, **kwargs).  The reason you can call self.Name() is because name has not been overridden.

I'm repeating myself here.  Does this crystalize it, or have I confused you further?

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, as it doesn't explain the difference in invocation between `__init__` and `Name`.

Comment: It is "bound" to function means that since it has inherited the method Name() so it can also be called by self.Name()? If thats true then I am getting it. Secondly why do we need to pass self as an argument , that is pass child to parent class?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to say it is that `self.method()` means "call the most specific implementation of `method` available" (i.e., the one furthest down the current object's inheritance tree).  In this case you don't wall to call `self.__init__`, because that would call `Employee.__init__` again.  You need to write `Person.__init__` (or use `super()`) to explicitly call an inherited method.

Because `Employee` does not define its own `Name` method, `Person.Name` is the most specific one available, so that is what is called by `self.Name()`.  If `Employee` defined its own `Name`, then that would be called by `self.Name()` instead.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I get it now! :) :)

Comment: One more question, when we need to call a method of parent class we need to pass the child (self) as an argument. Why is that so?

Comment: @ShahrozPunjwani: Whenever you call a method on a class (as in `Person.__init__`), you need to pass the instance as the first argument.  When you call the method on the instance (as in `self.Name`), you don't (it is automatically passed for you).